# display int values when using the CorePlot Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I have followed this [link](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/) for drawing the graph . Everything is fine but only thing I need to change is I have to display the intvalues instead of floatvalues on the x-axis (Instead of 0.0 , 2.0 ... I have to display the 0,2,...). Please let me know if I am not clear . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a number formatter for the axis labels on the CPTAxis class. Set the formatter up to not have decimal places, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I have to draw two graphs one is having decimals and another is having the float values . Please tell me how to do this .

Comment: Get the two axis x & y and apply formatter like this         NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];x.formatter = f; (get correct propertName from CPTAxis)

Comment: I think we can't write any allocations in the header file. Please tell me in which file I have to do this?

Comment: in the class where you are having coreplot implementations

Comment: Thank you arun it is working fine . I have marked your question as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the Floating number from axis with something like this

```
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

y.labelFormatter = formatter;
```

Thanks